# django-admin: command not found in HostGator shared hosting to start django project

Tags: python, django, shared-hosting

I am tring to setup Django in HostGator shared hosting server.

> python 2.6.6
>   django 1.3.1

I run this command in SSH shell.

```
django-admin startproject sitename

-jailshell: django-admin: command not found
```

How can i fix this.

Comment: Please don't try to host Django in that environment. Python 2.6.6 and Django 1.3.1 are years out of date and insecure. Tutorials and the Django docs won't help because it is so out of date. As an example,  running `django-admin startproject` won't work, because the command back then was `django-admin.py`.

Comment: I was tried to install new version of django but hostgator not allow this.

Comment: I that case you should use a different host, or don’t use Django.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will leave Hostgator. 
I will use Namecheap for this. They have build in app for many python(2, 3) package with django latest version.
Thanks for time